# How to place predefined number of agents to multiple regions in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic, region, agent-based-modeling

Let say I have a shapefile uploaded in AnyLogic with multiple regions (region1, region2,...region5). I have an excel file with a column "No. of people" [10,15,20,30,15] for those 5 regions. How can I place those agents to the corresponding regions? Also, I want to place those people in random locations. For instance, 10 people will be randomly placed in region1, 15 on region2, and so on.

It seems I can add those 10 people on region1 only. Is there any way I can add all sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this.. i didn't test and i don't know your database or agents

```
List <Tuple> rows=selectFrom(database).list();
for(Tuple t : rows){
     GISRegion region=findFirst(multi.getRegions(),r->r.getName().equals(t.get(database.region_name)));
     for(int i=0;i<(int)t.get(database.num_people);i++){
          MyAgent myAgent=add_myAgents();
         Point point=region.randomPointInside();
          myAgent.setLocation(point);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Felipe. I am getting couple of errors. First "multi cannot be resolved".  Here multi is a variable created from a Collection of multiple regions. Second MyAgent (in 6th line) error "MyAgent cannot be resolved to a type". Third, add_myAgents, error "add_myAgents()  is undefined for type my Agent".  For my case "People" is agent. So I wrote: MyAgent People = add_peoples(). Sorry, I am new on Java too.

Comment: this code is just a guideline... it's not for copy pasting

Comment: Yes, I got it. Actually I was trying to pointing out the locations of errors.

Comment: Hi @Felipe, I resolved all errors except one. The method add_myAgents() is undefined. What you exactly tried to do on that line of code? For my case "People" is agent name. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: add_YouAgentName() allows you to create an agent ...if your agents already exist you need to choose there what agent is going to the region

Comment: Hi Felipe, just to let you know that your provided code structure is working perfectly. I got my expected output. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: the define this answer as accepted